# Как сократить нули в выводе времени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

Код:

```
time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

возвращает время с нулями, т.е.:

> 05:34:47

Как можно убрать эти нули? Чтобы было:

> 5:34:47

Comment: Просто был немного занят и не было времени проверить ответ, а так спасибо :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хотя в документации [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) этого нет (или я пока это не нашел), но на [Python's strftime directives](https://strftime.org/) пишут, что можно выводить дату и время сразу как *decimal number*, поставив знак `-` после `%`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
    
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 9, 55, 34, 882835)
    
>>> print(now)
2021-02-01 09:55:34.882835
    
>>> print(now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
01-02-2021 09:57:53
```

А теперь с `-` (без 0) в дне, месяце и часе:

```
>>> print(now.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y %-H:%M:%S'))
1-2-2021 9:57:53
```

Упоминание *platform specific* поясняет отличие спецификации в зависимости от операционной системы: символ `-` - для Linux и `#` - для Windows, т.е.:

```
# Linux
mydatetime.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y %-H:%M:%S') 
    
# Windows
mydatetime.strftime('%#d-%#m-%Y %#H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import datetime

timestamp = 1528257322
date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print(date_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))                                   # 06:55:22
print(f'{int(date_time.strftime("%H"))}:{date_time.strftime("%M:%S")}') #  6:55:22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
s = s[0].replace('0', '') + s[1:]

print(s)
```